# variable addition within index returns nil in ruby

Tags: ruby

I've come across this error twice now in exercises when I'm trying to iterate over indexes in a string with a conditional.  When I break it all out with individual cases the logic seems to work, but Ruby doesn't like something about the way it's expressed.

```
def NumberAddition(str)

  def is_num(num)
    (0..9).include? num.to_i
  end

  i = 0
  sum = 0

  while i < str.length
    if is_num(str[i])
      if !is_num(str[i+1])
        sum += str[i].to_i
          else
        mult = str[i]
        n = 1
        while is_num(str[i+n])
          mult << str[i+n]
          n += 1
        end
        sum += mult.to_i
      end
    end
    i += 1
  end

  sum
end

NumberAddition("75Number9")
```

throws this error:

```
no implicit conversion of nil into String
(repl):18:in `NumberAddition'
```

for the line:

```
mult << str[i+n]
```

so obviously instead of returning, say, the string "5" for str[i+n],
where i=0 and n=1, it finds nil.  Is there a way to express this with my methodology or do I need to retool the whole loop?

Comment: Your code is too complex. Please, read this on how to create minimal, complete and verifiable example: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Your code is very un-Ruby-like. I'm guessing you've come from a language that makes heavy use of indices. Ruby doesn't. Instead, it mainly uses enumerators and blocks. You'll have to break that habit to use Ruby effectively. Once you've fixed your code I suggest you post it at [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/). There you will get good advice on how to improve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `is_num` function doesn't take into account that `nil.to_i` is `0`. That's why you're getting error, because you're trying to append nil to a string. You need to use something like this:

```
def is_num(num)
  # convert string to integer and back to string should be equal to string itself
  num.to_i.to_s == num 
end
```

Or, if you want to make sure that you concatenating strings, just convert the argument to a string

```
mult << str[i+n].to_s # nil gets converted to an empty string
```

Comment: It would be better to name the method `is_num?`. It could also be written: `def is_num?(num); !!Integer(num) rescue; end`. If `num` can be converted to an integer `Integer(num)` will return that integer, which is "truthy"; else `rescue` returns `nil`. `!!` converts a truthy value to `true` and a `falsy` value to `false`.